# Cannot infer arguments - Java

Tags: java

```
List<String> listT = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(varTypes));
List<String> listS = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(varStrings));
List<Integer> listI = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(varInts));
```

Вот создаю `ArrayList` для массивов, чтобы потом удалить в них значения, но у третьей строчки выскакивает ошибка у `<>` - `Cannot infer arguments`. Что за непонятная шляпа?

Массив: `int[] varInts = {0};`

Он изменяется по ходу выполнения программы

Comment: Наверное у вас там массив примитивных интов? Коли так, то должно помочь изменение массива на `Integer[]` вместо `int[]`

Comment: Покажи сами массивы или весь участок кода, если не много.

Answer (score 1):

Причина в том, что `ArrayList`, как и другие объекты, не могут принимать в качестве дженерик примитивы, только объекты.
Поэтому либо так

```
List<Integer> listI=Arrays.stream(varInts).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Либо по старинке

```
List<Integer> listI = new ArrayList<>(varInts.length);
for (int i : arr) {
    list.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
}
```

Comment: Ага это `ЮрийСПб` уже объяснил - или как нормальные люди сейчас делают, через оператор ссылку `::`.

Comment: да, но я написал в коммент, т.к. у меня не было достаточного времени и даже уверенности, что я могу написать приемлемый ответ. К тому же правила не запрещают писать ответ, основанный на чужом комментарии. Ну и в самом ответе, вроде, коммент даже и не упомянут) Лично у меня претензий к ответу нет, плюс поставил)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо)